# How does a redux connected component know when to re-render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm probably missing something very obvious and would like to clear myself.

Here's my understanding.
In a naive react component, we have `states` & `props`. Updating `state` with `setState` re-renders the entire component. `props` are mostly read only and updating them doesn't make sense.

In a react component that subscribes to a redux store, via something like `store.subscribe(render)`, it obviously re-renders for every time store is updated.

[react-redux](http://google.com) has a helper `connect()` that injects part of the state tree (that is of interest to the component) and actionCreators as `props` to the component, usually via something like

```js
const TodoListComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)
```

But with the understanding that a `setState` is essential for the `TodoListComponent` to react to redux state tree change(re-render), I can't find any `state` or `setState` related code in the `TodoList` component file. It reads something like this:

```js
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I am missing?

P.S I'm following the todo list example bundled with the [redux package](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos/src/containers).

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The `connect` function generates a wrapper component that subscribes to the store.  When an action is dispatched, the wrapper component's callback is notified.  It then runs your `mapState` function, and **shallow-compares** the result object from this time vs the result object from last time (so if you were to *rewrite* a redux store field with its same value, it would not trigger a re-render).  If the results are different, then it passes the results to your "real" component" as props.

Dan Abramov wrote a great simplified version of `connect` at ([connect.js](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1d19088790e70ac32ea636c025ba424e)) that illustrates the basic idea, although it doesn't show any of the optimization work.  I also have links to a number of articles on [Redux performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) that discuss some related ideas.

**update**

[React-Redux v6.0.0](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0) made some major internal changes to how connected components receive their data from the store.

As part of that, I wrote a post that explains how the `connect` API and its internals work, and how they've changed over time:

**[Idiomatic Redux: The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/)**

Comment: Thanks! Are you the same person who helped me the other day @ HN - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12307621 with useful links? 

Nice to meet you :)

Comment: Yup, that's me :)  I spend _way_ too much time looking for discussions on Redux online -   Reddit, HN, SO, Medium, and various other places.  Glad to help!  (Also FYI, I highly recommend the Reactiflux chat channels on Discord.  Lots of people hanging out there and answering questions.  I'm usually online there evenings US EST.  Invite link is at http://reactiflux.com .)

Comment: Assuming this answered the question, mind accepting the answer? :)

Comment: Is it comparing the objects themselves or the properties of those before/after objects? If it's the latter, does it only check the first level, is that what you mean by "shallow?"

Comment: Yes, a "shallow equality check" means to compare the first level fields of each object: `prev.a === current.a && prev.b === current.b && .....`. That assumes that any data changes will result in new references, which means immutable data updates are required instead of direct mutation.

Comment: Thanks, I really like that simplified connect gist. But it seems to contradict what you are saying here. In the gist the wrapper subscribes to the store and does a `this.forceUpdate()` every time the store is changed; regardless of the changes to the props going into the wrapped component. Is that prop comparison part of the 'optimization work' you mention in your answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The real implementation is far more sophisticated.  I recently wrote a post that goes into great detail on how the internals actually work:  [Idiomatic Redux: The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/).

Comment: So if you had a super component containing sub components. If the super component was connected to the redux store and received a new nested object where the changes only pertain to the subcomponent, instead of only re-rendering the subcomponent, we end up re-rendering the entire component tree even if the super component doesn't change visually?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai : Mmm... yes and no. With React-Redux v5 and v7 (current), the update checks are done in selectors outside the component tree. React is only involved once the selectors determine the component needs to re-render. However, React's default behavior is that if a component renders, React renders all of its descendants recursively. So, if you only have a top-level component connected, odds are the entire tree will re-render as every time.

Comment: why in some case, my props has changed in the same component but I can not see this component re-render?

Comment: @markerikson can you Please add an answer to my this bounty question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885139/how-can-i-get-the-state-value-in-the-reducer-of-createslice

Comment: @markerikson, if an action was dispatched, but the reducer returned the same state (`return state;`, indicating nothing needs to change), will `connect` still run? It currently runs in my code, but I thought it should not.  Feels like a wasted cycle to make every component run the `connect` callback for this "no change" case.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "will `connect` run?".  The `connect` function itself only ever ran once, to generate the new component type. The _store subscription callback_ will run, because it _always_ runs regardless of whether the store state changed or not. However, we then immediately check if the new state is identical to the old state, and if so, bail out of any further subscription behavior: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/#ui-updates-require-store-immutability

Answer (score 15):

My answer is a little out of left field.  It sheds light on a problem that led me to this post.  In my case it seemed the app was Not re-rendering, even though it received new props.
React devs had an answer to this often asked question something to the tune that if the (store) was mutated, 99% of the time that's the reason react won't re-render.
Yet nothing about the other 1%.  Mutation was not the case here.

---

TLDR;

> `componentWillReceiveProps` is how the `state` can be kept synced with the new `props`.

Edge Case: Once `state` updates, *then* the app *does* re-render !

---

**It turn out that if your app is using only `state` to display its elements, `props` can update, but `state` won't, so no re-render.**

I had `state` that was dependent on `props` received from redux `store`. The data I needed wasn't in the store yet, so I fetched it from `componentDidMount`, as is proper.  I got the props back, when my reducer updated store, because my component is connected via mapStateToProps.  But the page didn't render, and state was still full of empty strings.

An example of this is say a user loaded an "edit post" page from a saved url.  You have access to the `postId` from the url, but the info isn't in `store` yet, so you fetch it.  The items on your page are controlled components - so all the data you're displaying is in `state`.

Using redux, the data was fetched, store was updated, and the component is `connect`ed, but the app didn't reflect the changes.  On closer look, `props` were received, but app didn't update. `state` didn't update.

Well, `props` will update and propagate, but `state` won't.
You need to specifically tell `state` to update.

You can't do this in `render()`, and `componentDidMount` already finished it's cycles.

**`componentWillReceiveProps` is where you update `state` properties that depend on a changed `prop` value.**

Example Usage:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if (this.props.post.category !== nextProps.post.category){
    this.setState({
      title: nextProps.post.title,
      body: nextProps.post.body,
      category: nextProps.post.category,
    })
  }      
}
```

I must give a shout out to this article that enlightened me on the solution that dozens of other posts, blogs, and repos failed to mention.  Anyone else who has had trouble finding an answer to this evidently obscure problem, Here it is:

[ReactJs component lifecycle methods — A deep dive](https://hackernoon.com/reactjs-component-lifecycle-methods-a-deep-dive-38275d9d13c0)

> `componentWillReceiveProps` is where you'll update `state` to keep in sync with `props` updates.
>
> Once `state` updates, *then* fields depending on `state` *do* re-render !

Comment: From `React 16.3` onwards,  you [should](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props) use the `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`. But in fact, you shouldn't even do all that as articulated [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

Comment: it doesnt work, whenever state changed then componentWillReceiveProps will work so many case I try this doesnt work. Especially, multi level nested or complex props so I have to assign component with an ID and trigger change for it and update state to re-render new data

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a summary of Brian Vaughn's article entitled [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) (June 07, 2018).

Deriving state from props is an anti-pattern in all its forms. Including using the older `componentWillReceiveProps` and the newer `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Instead of deriving state from props, consider the following solutions.

Two best practice recommendations

Recommendation 1. Fully controlled component

```
function EmailInput(props) {
  return <input onChange={props.onChange} value={props.email} />;
}
```

Recommendation 2. Fully uncontrolled component with a key

```
// parent class
class EmailInput extends Component {
  state = { email: this.props.defaultEmail };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />;
  }
}

// child instance
<EmailInput
  defaultEmail={this.props.user.email}
  key={this.props.user.id}
/>
```

Two alternatives if, for whatever reason, the recommendations don't work for your situation.

Alternative 1: Reset uncontrolled component with an ID prop

```
class EmailInput extends Component {
  state = {
    email: this.props.defaultEmail,
    prevPropsUserID: this.props.userID
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Any time the current user changes,
    // Reset any parts of state that are tied to that user.
    // In this simple example, that's just the email.
    if (props.userID !== state.prevPropsUserID) {
      return {
        prevPropsUserID: props.userID,
        email: props.defaultEmail
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Alternative 2: Reset uncontrolled component with an instance method

```
class EmailInput extends Component {
  state = {
    email: this.props.defaultEmail
  };

  resetEmailForNewUser(newEmail) {
    this.setState({ email: newEmail });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As I know only thing redux does, on change of store's state is calling componentWillRecieveProps if your component was dependent on mutated state and then you should force your component to update
it is like this

1-store State change-2-call(componentWillRecieveProps(()=>{3-component state change}))