# Figure out if a component is going to be updated or not in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386128/how-does-a-redux-connected-component-know-when-to-re-render#answer-40386189) answer, react redux shallow compares the output of `mapStateToProps` to figure out whether or not a component needs to be re-rendered..

I have a component which is not re-rendering despite a change in the relevant state.
I attached breakpoints to the [shallowEqual](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/utils/shallowEqual.js) function in the react redux source code but found out that the function, in fact, returns false(i.e the objects being compared in case of my component are not equal).So ideally my component should re-render. I am thus unable to figure out why my component is not re-rendering. I'm guessing it's because of the performance optimizations in the `connect` function.

Is there any way to print the outputs of the checks being made in the connect function regarding the re-rendering of a component

Answer (score 3):

If you want to confirm if it is react-redux optimisations getting in the way, you can turn them off using the [`options` argument](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) of the `connect` function.  e.g.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, undefined, { pure: false })(YourComponent)
```

This will bypass all equality checks and allow `YourComponent` to re-render on every state or prop change.  If it's still not re-rendering your component, then the issue is elsewhere.

**Remember** to remove the option before committing your changes (unless it's actually required).

Answer (score 0):

There is another aspect to take in consideration: the **reconciliation**. Your component might be updated but **maybe** Reactjs figures out that the DOM result of your component **will be the same**, so it doesn't need to be re-rendered. I strongly suggest you to implement the function `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` inside your component and compare the `this.props` and `nextProps` by yourself and understand the situation.