# How do I allow connect to rerender an object based on state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the below example, I would like component to rerender when list is updated. But even though connect is passed new state, it doesn't rerender the component.

I know that connect performs shallow compare, but don't know how to make it compare the values of object. I couldn't find any example of connect with the options enabled.

I have seen [How does a redux connected component know when to re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386128/how-does-a-redux-connected-component-know-when-to-re-render) and some more but it doesn't help either.

I have tried

```
const ConnectList = connect(mapStateToProps,null,null,{areStatesEqual : () => false})(List)
```

to just try to make it rerender for any change. That doesn't seem to be working as well.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux'

function testReducer (state=null,action) {
    console.log(`Reducer: Reducer received action ${action.type}. ${action.comment}`)
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LIST': {
            return ({ ...state, list: action.list })
        }

        case 'OTHER': {
            return ({ ...state, other: action.other })
        }
        default:
            return state
    }

}

function testAction() {
    return {
        type: 'LIST',
        list: ['first','second'],
        comment: `This will trigger both connect() and mount Component List mount because, both reducer and connect changes state after this action`
    }
}

function testActionChange() {
    return {
        type: 'LIST',
        list: ['first','second','third'],
        comment: `This will trigger both connect() and mount Component List mount because, both reducer and connect changes state after this action`
    }
}

function testOther() {
    return {
        type: 'OTHER',
        other: `some other value`,
        comment: `This will trigger connect(), but not mount Component List because the return from connect() doesn't change`
    }
}

function inertAction() {
    return {
        type: 'INERT',
        comment: 'This action should not trigger either connect() or mount Component List , because reducer returs the same state'
    }
}

const store = createStore(testReducer, [thunk])

store.dispatch(testAction())

//Dispatch an action after 2 secs
setTimeout(store.dispatch.bind(null,testOther()),2000)
setTimeout(store.dispatch.bind(null,inertAction()),4000)
setTimeout(store.dispatch.bind(null,testActionChange()),6000)


class List extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(`Component List mounted`)
    }

    render(){
        const {list} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                {list.map((element) => {
                    return(<Element key={element} element={element} />)
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({list}){
    console.log(`connect() triggered`)
    return( {
        list
    })
}

const ConnectList = connect(mapStateToProps)(List)

class Element extends Component {
    render(){
        const {element} = this.props
        return(
            <div>{element}</div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}> 
                    <ConnectList />
                </Provider>, 
                document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Output

[image]

Added console.log in connect.
[image]

Comment: I think, there is no way componentDidMount is going to be called, only render would be called

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognize the syntax your using in mapStateToProps

try:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log(`connect() triggered`)
    const list = state.list;
    return { list };
}
```

Comment: connect triggers. But the problem is it does not render the component

Comment: can you console.log what returning from mapStateToProps on every state change?

Comment: I added. But also noticed something else. Even though componentDidMount did not get called, render did get called

Comment: maybe use shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) and do the compare there instead of pushing it down to render

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that connect in fact calls the component. But only the render method. So I had to move my action creator calls at componentDidMount to a middleware in redux to add appropriate dispatcher when state changes.