# How can I get the state value in the reducer of createSlice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit in my react project. In a reducer of createSlice, I want to use the existing array of entities from the state and append the new array,before reducing the final state. But I'm unable to get the state value.

Here is the reducer code

```
export const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: initialUsersState,
  reducers: {
    usersCreated: (state: UsersState, action) => {
      // in real, return count from the server and append the entities on front-end only?
      const { count, entities } = action.payload;
      const existingEntities = state.entities;
      const newEntities = [...existingEntities, ...entities];
      const totalCount = state.totalCount+count;
      return {
        ...state,
        entities: newEntities,
        totalCount: totalCount,
        listLoading: false,
        error: null,
      };
    },
}});
```

When I debug the state.entites variable, it looks like this

[image]

**Is there a way to access the current state value in reducer/extraReducer to recreate the state as per desire?**

Because I assume directly working with state value outside the reducer would be a bad practice. Please guide me, if I'm wrong.

**Edit**

The [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-nightingale-frp6b?file=/src/reducer.ts) created by @Linda Paiste is working fine, that means we can access the state variable in reducer but we can't debug the state variable to dig deeper what is that state variable is holding at the moment, as Redux-toolkit is dealing the state in it's own way...
As obvious from the debugging screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'll try to create a code sandbox today and linked it here.

Comment: @karlmarxlopez still waiting for your input :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-nightingale-frp6b?file=/src/reducer.ts

Comment: It says there's a 15 hour grace period on the bounty. But I'm not clear exactly what it is that you want to achieve. Is it just to have better debugging? You can use the [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) extension and that seems to work for me. I looked at the Immer docs as suggested by @karlmaxlopex and [this page](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/example-reducer) explains how the previous state is a "draft" rather than an actual object.  So you can't can't console.log it but there is a workaround via JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only reference the current slice state.

Therefore your only options are passing the desired `entities` as action's `payload` or implementing this action as a thunk [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) and use `getState()` from its API.

Comment: Can I use Redux Reducer to achive the goal. I mean, would I be able to get state variables in Redux reducers?

Comment: Yes, refer to docs https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Answer (score 22):

Summarizing the info in the comments from myself and @karlmaxlopez:

I copied your code into a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-nightingale-frp6b?file=/src/reducer.ts) and found that the code **does** execute as expected.  You are able to append to the `state.entities` array as if it were a normal array, even though the value of `state.entities` appears as a `Proxy` when inspecting or `null` when logging.

This is because redux-toolkit uses Immer to prevent you from directly mutating the state.  In a normal redux reducer you receive the previous `state` as a function argument. The responsibility is placed on you as the user to not mutate it and instead to return a new object with the updated values by using non-mutating methods such as object spreading, array concat, etc.  This is what you have done in your `usersCreated` reducer, which is totally fine.

But redux-toolkit and Immer opens up an additional possibility for how to write a reducer.  In an [Immer reducer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/example-reducer), the `state` argument that is received by your function is a "draft" object.  This means that you can directly mutate the draft object without causing any issues because it is just a draft and not the true `state`.

It also means that when you try to examine this previous state, it will behave strangely because of being just a draft and not the actual object that you are expecting it to be.

If you want to `console.log` a draft value, you can do this by calling `console.log(current(value))` using the immer `current` function, which is included in the redux toolkit package. (edited per @markerikson's comment).

As far as inspecting the changes made to your state by each action, I recommend using [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en).  I am able to see what actions were dispatched, the current state, what changes were made, etc.
[image: Redux DevTools screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I still have 5 hours to award bounty :) I'm already using Redux DevTools. Actully,  I was expecting something to get control of recreating state by applying store freeze strategy as we do in Angular :) I think we should have flags(on/off) in createSlice to get control of, how we will be changing the state

Comment: Correct answer here, although I'd recommend using [the Immer `current` API exported from RTK](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current) rather than `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Life saver, this should be the first search result, upvoting.

Answer (score 8):

You can use current function provided by toolkit out of the box to get the current state value.

```
import {
    createSlice,
    current
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const parserSlice = createSlice({
    name: ReducerKeys.parser,
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateData: (state, action) => {
            console.log(action.payload, current(state), 'updating');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use current function provided by toolkit out of the box to get the current state value.

Comment: But it seems current produces only read-only object.

Answer (score 4):

I am simply copying/pasting an equivalent of the CodeSandbox solution by @Linda Paiste, so it's faster to find and reuse.

```
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
   users: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    userCreated: (state, action) => {
      const newUser = action.payload;
      const existingUsers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.users));
      const newUsers = [...existingUsers, newUser];
      state.users= newUsers;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to retrieve a copy of the real state:

```
const getCurrentState = (state) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

then use this inside the reducer:

```
const currentState = getCurrentState(state);
```